# Trying to hide some methods: using declaration shadows template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, private, using, public

My aim is to hide some public methods of some legacy classes while allowing public access to others. For example when I have

```
struct foo {
    void call_me();
    void dont_call_me();                            
};
```

then this works like a charm:

```
struct bar : private foo {
    using foo::call_me;
};
```

What I would like to have is some `magic` template such that `magic<foo,&foo::call_me>` "uses" `foo::call_me` (and possibly more when it can be done variadic). I tried this

```
template <typename T,void (T::*mem_fun)()>
struct dont_call_me_foo : private T {
    using T::mem_fun;
};
```

I didnt really expect this to work, but still I was a bit surprised by the compiler error:

```
error: declaration of ‘using T::mem_fun’ shadows template parameter
  using T::mem_fun;
           ^~~~~~~
prog.cpp:18:22: note: template parameter ‘mem_fun’ declared here
 template <typename T,void (T::*mem_fun)()>
                      ^~~
```

**Is is possible to fix `dont_call_me_foo` without somehow reimplementing the method?**

Prefereably C++11, but if anything later helps, I would also be interested.

Comment: Macro should be a perfect choice here.